# Explicit construction of retraction for Brouwer's fixed point theorem (disk)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

So I'm trying to prove the Brouwer fixed-point theorem for the disk, arguing by contradiction and using the theorem that states that there is no retraction from the unit disk $D^2$ to the unit circle $S^1$.  Assuming that for all $x\in D^2$, $f(x)\neq x$, we see that the line connecting $f(x)$ and $x$ is not degenerate, i.e. not a point.  I'm attempting to define the retraction $r:D^2\to S^1$ as the map that sends $x$ to an intersection of the line connecting $x$ and $f(x)$ and the circle, particularly the one with closer distance to $x$, so that if $x\in S^1$, then $r(x)=x$.  However, I'm having a bit of an issue explicitly defining this function; I used the equations given here as a guide:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

but to show which one of the intersections is closest to $x$ seems like a very algebraically messy process.  Is there an easier way to construct this retraction?  If I've left anything out, I apologize, of course.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note here:

> I'm attempting to define the retraction $r:D^2\to S^1$ as the map that sends $x$ to an intersection of the line connecting $x$ and $f(x)$ and the circle, particularly the one with closer distance to $x$, so that if $x\in S^1$, then $r(x)=x$.

$x$ is not sent to the intersection that is closer to $x$.

Instead, $x$ is sent to the intersection with the circle of the ray from $f(x)$ through $x$. This exists and the mapping is continuous, provided there is no fixed point.

This is rather easy to realize provided that there is a way to write an explicit algebraic expression if needed. That there is one is generally clear from experience in calclus and other courses generally taken before a topology course. If you still want all the details, you can consult Robert Israel's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/422627/230418) and supply more details yourself to get an explicit expression.